# How to center list items in flex box navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

I have the following code:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.flex > li {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="flex">
    <!--Logo as a link-->
    <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Logo</a></li>
    <li><a>REGISTER</a></li>
    <li><a>LOGIN</a></li>
    <!--Search Bar-->
    <li class="search_bar">
      <form method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
        <input name="query" type="text" placeholder="Zip Code or City/Town">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success text-white my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"></button>
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0jh3fud9/2/

How do I center the list items ("LOGO", "REGISTER" "LOGIN", "SEARCH") within the border they are in?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the commented CSS rules to your li elements ([see updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0jh3fud9/3/)):

```
.flex > li {
    display: flex; // <-- make flex items
    align-items: center; // <-- center vertically in box
    justify-content: center; // <-- center horizontally in box
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;
    align-items: center;
}
```

This will make each of the list items also behave as a flex item and will center them horizontally and vertically in their parent.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is declare your elements as a `flex` container as you've done.

Add the `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;` properties to them, but you don't really do that here, since there is no space in where you could center anything hence it doesn't know what to center it to.

Remove `flex: 1;` and I recommend adding `padding: 10px;` and a `margin: 5px;` and it should work. If you want them to be close to each other then only add padding.

P.S. you could also use a `text-align: center;`